# setting css variables (--clr-default) to external data in Nuxt 3

Tags: vue-composition-api, nuxtjs3, vue-script-setup

I retreive the required color data from a dataset in Sanity.io and set it to the relevant state in the pinia store. But I'm not sure how to set the value of my css custom properties with the data. using:

```
<script setup>
const siteSettings = useSiteSettingsStore();
onMounted(() => {
  const root = document.querySelector(":root");
root.style.setProperty("--clr-default", siteSettings.clrDefault.Hex);
root.style.setProperty("--clr-primary", siteSettings.clrPrimary.Hex);
root.style.setProperty("--clr-secondary", siteSettings.clrSecondary.Hex);
});
</script>
```

the error returned indicates that document.querySelector cannot be accessed on the server side, so how do I access and set these values please.